# Can main and test net interact?

Tags: testnets, private-blockchain, blockchain-interoperation

is there direct way to make a contract on either the main or test net to communicate with a contract on the other net?

This could be generalized as asking if a contract on private chain can communicate with another one contracts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `main-net` and `test-net` are two separate blockchains, therefore they cannot share same contract state.

Technically, its as different as Bitcoin blockchain and Ethereum blockchain. Now btc-relay made it possible to interchange values between them. People made btc-relay because the world needs it.

In your case there is no real reason to communicate with a test-net from a main-net.

#### `Test-net` is for testing, and testing only.

Comment: Are there any bridges?

Comment: none, that i am aware of.